# Show that a function given by series is not continuous at 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, continuity

How to show that the function
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}\sin(nx), \quad x \geq 0,
$$
is not continuous at $0$?

The problem is that there is $n^2$ in the power of $e$. If $n$ was there, I would be able to calculate the sum explicitly

Comment: Moreover, numerically the limit is $$\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)=\frac12$$

Comment: I would like to upvote because this is an interesting question. However, OP, you have shown no effort or thoughts on the problem...

Comment: @jjagmath, the continuity question is raised about 0. Why do we need to consider these details?

Comment: @MathFail I think $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty,\ $ although this is more my intuition than being super precise, so I am not certain of it. I would be surprised if the limit is $1/2$ as I do not see where that even comes from.

Comment: @AdamRubinson You can see my (edited) answer sort to see where does the $1/2$ come from.

Comment: It seems you are right and my intuition reasoning was faulty. WA confirms roughly $1/2$ so now it is not so surprising: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=integralof+Power%5Be%2C%5C%2840%29-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D0.0001%5C%2841%29%5Dsin%5C%2840%290.0001x%5C%2841%29+with+respect+to+x+between+x%3D0+and+x%3D31416

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle f : x \mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}\sin(nx)$.

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. One has
$$f \left(\dfrac{1}{N^2} \right) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right) +  \sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right)$$

Let's study the two terms of this summation : we denote them $$A_N :=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right) \quad \text{and} \quad B_N := \sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right)$$

For the first one, one has
\begin{align*} \left| A_N - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\frac{n}{N^2}\right| & = \left| \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\left[\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right) - \frac{n}{N^2}\right]\right| \\
& =  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\left[\frac{n}{N^2}-\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right)  \right] \\
& \leq   \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\left(\frac{n^3}{6N^6} \right) \\
& \leq   \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{n^3}{6N^6}   =\frac{N^2(N-1)^2}{24N^6} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{+\infty} 0 \\
\end{align*}

Since $$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\frac{n}{N^2} =  \dfrac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\frac{n}{N} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{+\infty} \int_0^1 xe^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{1-e^{-1}}{2}$$

one deduce that $$\boxed{\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} A_N = \dfrac{1-e^{-1}}{2}}$$

Now, let's do the same with $B_N$ : similarly, one has

\begin{align*}   \left| B_N - \sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\frac{n}{N^2}\right| & = \left| \sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\left[\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right) - \frac{n}{N^2}\right]\right| \\
& =  \sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\left[\frac{n}{N^2}-\sin\left(\frac{n}{N^2}\right)  \right] \\
& \leq   \sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\left(\frac{n^3}{6N^6} \right) \\
& = \dfrac{1}{6N^6}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=kN}^{(k+1)N-1} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2} n^3 \\
& \leq \dfrac{1}{6N^6}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=kN}^{(k+1)N-1} e^{-k^2} n^3   = O \left( \dfrac{1}{N^2}\right) \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{+\infty} 0
\end{align*}

Moreover, one has

$$\int_{N+1}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{t}{N}\right)^2}t dt\leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}n \leq \int_N^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{t}{N}\right)^2}t dt$$

i.e.

$$\dfrac{N^2}{2}e^{- \left(\frac{N+1}{N} \right)^2}\leq \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}n \leq \dfrac{N^2}{2}e^{-1}$$

so we get the equivalent $ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}n \sim \dfrac{N^2}{2}e^{-1}$, which leads to $$\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\frac{n}{N^2} = \dfrac{e^{-1}}{N} + \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}\frac{n}{N^2} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{-1}}{2}$$

so finally
$$\boxed{\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} B_N = \dfrac{e^{-1}}{2} }$$

We deduce that
$$\boxed{\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} f \left( \dfrac{1}{N^2}\right) = \dfrac{1-e^{-1}}{2} + \dfrac{e^{-1}}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \neq 0 = f(0)}$$

and hence, $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $x$, where $0<x<1$, let $m=\lfloor\sqrt\frac1x\rfloor$, and $n=m^2$

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-k^2/n}\sin \frac kn+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty e^{-k^2/n}\sin \frac kn$$

the tail part:

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty e^{-k^2/n}\sin \frac kn\right|\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty e^{-k^2/n}\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{1}{e-1}\cdot e^{-n}$$

the body part:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-k^2/n}\sin \frac kn\ge \sum_{k=1}^m e^{-\frac{k^2}{m^2}}\sin \left(\frac k{m^2}\right)\ge \sum_{k=1}^m e^{-\frac{k^2}{m^2}}\frac2\pi \left(\frac k{m^2}\right)=\frac2\pi\sum_{k=1}^m e^{-\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^2} \cdot\frac k{m}\cdot \frac1m$$

hence

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)\ge\frac2\pi\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}x~dx=\frac{e-1}{\pi e}$$

Comment: Although you did not need it to prove the discontinuity, how can one show that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ (finite or not) exists?

Comment: @AnneBauval You can have a look at my answer. Although I only prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(1/n^2) = 1/2$, I am pretty sure that the same ideas can be used to prove the (slightly more general) fact that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x) = 1/2$.

Comment: @MathFail: your answer is not using any $x$ with $0<x<1$, but rather it is using $x=1/m^2$. In particular it doesn't show that the limit exists, but rather that  $\limsup_{x\geq0}f(x) >0$. Maybe it should be edited to clarify both things.